# Is it safe to convert char * to const unsigned char *?

Tags: c

We are using `char *` and the lib we use is using `const unsigned char *`, so we convert to `const unsigned char *`

```
// lib
int asdf(const unsigned char *vv);

//ours
char *str = "somestring";
asdf((const unsigned char*)str);
```

Is it safe? any pitfall?

Comment: OK, yet the other way a round is  a problem on _very rare_ machines.  De-referencing a `unsigned char` via a `signed char *` may trigger an exception.  Doubt any machine exists anymore  that  exploits that corner of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is safe.

```
char *str = "somestring";
```

str is a constant,you could change str point to another string:

```
str = "some";//right
```

but you can't change the string which str is pointing now

```
str[0]='q';//wrong
```

so it is safe to use const to convert a constant to constant

if the asdf() only use to show the string,likes printf() or puts() ,you no need to const,because you are not change the string.

if you use const it will be safer.when you implementing the asdf(),it will make sure you can't write the wrong code likes "str[0]='q';" because you can't compile it.

if there are no const,you will find the error until you running the program.

Answer (score 0):

If it's being treated as a string by that interface, there should be no problem at all. You don't even need to add the `const` in your cast if you don't want to - that part is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is always safe to convert pointers from one type to another (except between function pointers and data pointers, unless your implementation provides an extension that allows that). It's only the *dereferencing* that is unsafe.

But dereferencing a pointer to any signedness of `char` is always safe (from a type aliasing perspective, at least).

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't break anything in the compiler if you pass a `char*` where an `unsigned char*` was expected by using a cast. The `const` part is unproblematic -- it's just indicating that the function won't modify the argument via its pointer.

In many cases it doesn't matter whether `char` values are treated as signed or unsigned -- it's usually only a problem when performing arithmetic or comparing the sizes of values. However, if the function is expressly defined to take an `unsigned char*`, I guess there's a chance that it really requires the input data to be unsigned, for some arithmetical reason. If you're treating your character data as signed elsewhere, then it's possible that there is an incompatibility between your data and the data expected by the function.

In many cases, however, developers write "unsigned" to mean "I will not be doing arithmetic on this data", so the signedness probably won't matter.